# How to set state of a specific object in array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, state

I have a list of Objects in Array, which contain user values. I want to change a specific object depending on user choice. To be more specific, I have a Table, for each user, there is a property ischecked which is false on default. I want that when a user clicks on a checkbox, isChecked property changes to true.

[image: Table]

Here is my Function which displays the table data.

```
// Display Table Data
  renderTableData = () => {
    return this.state.students.map((student, index) => {
      const { isChecked, name, age, email } = student; //destructuring
      return (
        <tr className={classes.tableRow} key={index}>
          <td className={classes.tableDataSpecial}>
            <div className={classes.content}>
              {" "}
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isChecked}
                onChange={this.toggleCheckHandler}
              />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td className={classes.tableData}>{name}</td>
          <td className={classes.tableData}>{age}</td>
          <td className={classes.tableData}>{email}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };
```

Here is my State

```
 state = {

    students: [
      { isChecked: false, name: "Wasif", age: 21, email: "wasif@email.com" },
      { isChecked: false, name: "Ali", age: 19, email: "ali@email.com" },
      { isChecked: false, name: "Saad", age: 16, email: "saad@email.com" },
      { isChecked: false, name: "Asad", age: 25, email: "asad@email.com" }
    ]
  };
```

and here is my **toggleCheckHandler** function

```
toggleCheckHandler = e => {
    console.log(e.target);
  };
```

e.target gives me DOM content. So how to target that specific object.

**For Example**, I want to set isChecked of **Wasif** to true, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the `index` parameter of your callback function. This could look something like:

```
// Display Table Data
  renderTableData = () => {
    return this.state.students.map((student, index) => {
      const { isChecked, name, age, email } = student; //destructuring
      return (
        <tr className={classes.tableRow} key={index}>
          <td className={classes.tableDataSpecial}>
            <div className={classes.content}>
              {" "}
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isChecked}
                onChange={() => this.toggleCheckHandler(index)}
              />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td className={classes.tableData}>{name}</td>
          <td className={classes.tableData}>{age}</td>
          <td className={classes.tableData}>{email}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };

toggleCheckHandler = (index) => {
    const students = this.state.students;
    students[index].isChecked = !students[index].isChecked;
    this.setState({
        students: students
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass any data related to specific student (whole 'student' object, email, or id of this student).
Something like this:

```
const { isChecked, name, age, email } = student; //destructuring
return (
  ...
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={isChecked}
    onChange={()=>this.toggleCheckHandler(email)}
  />
  ...
)

toggleCheckHandler = email => {
 console.log(email); // or id
};
```

Then you can easily find an object in array by email (or id).

Comment: That works. Thank you, but is there any more efficient solution available? Eventually, I will have a lot of data.

Comment: You can do better if you install form manager like Formik or react-form-hooks. It manages the states easily with field array and validation.

Comment: As I already mentioned, you can define a unique ID for each user. And use similar approach to any other data sets: users, teachers, schedule, whatever. I don't know how exactly you will define ID, how it is stored, etc., but, for instance, you can use something like this: {id: 'student093432987'},  {id: 'teacher2554154'}, ...
There is no need to attach it to DOM event.